# How to synchronize colorified through subshell stderr with main shell's stdout in Bash?

Tags: bash, colors

There is a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2> >(while read; do echo >&2 -ne '\e[1;36m'; echo >&2 -n "$REPLY"; echo >&2 -e '\e[m'; done)
echo line1
echo errline1 >&2
echo line2
echo errline2 >&2
echo line3
echo err line 3 >&2
```

The second line is intended to colorify stderr.

The result is:

```
line1
line2
line3
errline1
errline2
err line 3
```

expected:

```
line1
errline1
line2
errline2
line3
err line 3
```

#### How to synchronize colorified stderr from subshell with main shell's stdout?

Comment: BTW, I just edited my answer to the  linked question to explicitly show how to use it to do the kind of colorization you're looking for here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thank you.